# C# how to locate ToolStripDropDown in both screens

Tags: c#, toolstripdropdown

I want my combobox to strech ToolStripDropDown  through both screens if my item is too long. Currently, show (int x, int y) is used and it shows the item on one screen or the other depending on how far it is from the left side of the first screen. Is there a way to do it? Thanks

Comment: No, it intentionally avoids this.  This very rarely works well in practice, even if you line up the monitors as accurately as possible and they have very thin bezels.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: So there is no existing way to support display with 2 screens?